# what is the use of - (id)init in NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nsobject

Today I was going through some of the online  codes and I found some `NSObject` Class.

Some are having:

```
- (id)init
 {  
      self = [super init];

      return self;
 
 }
```

And some doesn't have it.

Then I also tried this in my Sample Code. I was totally confused. Before this I was thinking that we must write `-(id)init` method to instantiate a NSObject Class. But now it is working without it.

Here are my some of my doubts:

> 1. is -(id)init method really necessary?
> 2. What happens if we don't use it.
> 3. If we don't write `init` method even then my code works. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an empty `-init` has absolutely no function.

`NSObject` already has `-init` method. And methods in Objective-C are inherited.

It's the same as overriding any other method and just call super:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [super someMethod];
}
```

Comment: so we have to explictly wirte it only when we want to assign some values.right ? But Why some people only write `self = [super init]; return self;`

Comment: @RahulMishra It could be legacy code or there was originally some value assigned. It can also be a part of template. Multiple reasons. You would have to ask them. From functional point there is no reason.

Comment: Ok got that :) thanks .. So it means We can always work without writing this code snipet ?

Comment: @RahulMishra Yes. In Objective-C the initializers work the same as all other methods. In other languages there are rules for the inheritance of constructors/initializers but in Obj-C they are always inherited. If your method (initializer or not) just calls `super` implementation, then you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find answers to your questions in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) on initializers. I'd recommend you go through those materials, they will clarify a lot of things.

To sum up the documentation with regards to your questions:

> is -(id)init method really necessary?

If you don't need to perform extra logic when your class is instanced, then you don't need to implement an `init` in your class.

> What happens if we don't use it.

Even if you don't need to implement it in your subclasses, you need to call it when creating a new object, e.g. `[[MyClass alloc] init]`

> If we don't write init method even then my code works. Why?

As I wrote above, you don't need to declare one for your class, but you need to call it. Otherwise your code might not properly work.

`[super init]` is highly recommended to give a chance for the superclass to also properly configure the newly created object.

Answer (score 1):

Not calling super init is an error, and results are undefined. (Bad things my happen)

Comment: is it not called automatically ?

Comment: No it is not called automatically. You are ALWAYS supposed to call super init if it is defined.

Comment: Suppose I have created a NSObject Class and define a method of type void nothing else...even then I have to define `super init`?

Comment: You don't have to define super init, you have to call super init, as in the code you posted in your question.

Comment: To be clear: You don't have to implement an init method, but if you do, you must call super init if your superclass implements it (As almost all objects do.)

Answer (score -1):

-init() is initializer of NSObject. If a user creates a Person Class which inherits NSObject. It can override this initializer, or one can create their own custom initializer as show below
eg.

```
    class Person : NSObject
    {
        let name:String
        //Initializer inherited from NSObject
        override init()
        {
           super.init()
        }
        //Custom Initializer
        init(withName name:String)
        {
           super.init()
           self.name = name
        }

    }
```